# How to work with "long living entities" or "longer living persistence context"?

Tags: java, jpa

I am currently working on a medium sized, desktop-based administration and configuration tool implemented in Java using JavaFx, google-guice, and hibernate for its jpa implementation.

Until now i got away with a single `EntityManager` injected as a `@Singleton`. Meaning that i had this EntityManager "open" from start to shutdown. All loaded entites were permanently known in the context and I barely had any problems with this approach. Although i know/believe it is not the best solution (but easy and a I had no time to redesign the application).

Now the application gets extended and I have to use multiple persistence units simultaneously.

I could try to get my current singleton-approach working with using something like:

```
@Inject 
@PersistenceContext(name="JPA-Unit1")
@Singleton
private EntityManager em;
```

*It never felt perfect, but that feels "ugly"*. And since I had severe problems getting multiple persistence contexts working with guice, I had to do a lot of reasearch on this topic.

And i came across several blogs SO-questions either mentioning that an instance of the EntityManager should only live as long it is needed or some extended persistence contexts.

Since I useJavaFx in place I use the [*Property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/ObjectProperty.html) classes to bind the data directly into the UI.

Simplified user entity (property-based access):

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "USERS")
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM User u")
    public class User implements Serializable {

        [...]

        private final SimpleStringProperty loginProperty = new SimpleStringProperty();

        public User() {
        }

        public String getLogin() {
            return this.loginProperty.get();
        }

        public void setLogin(String login) {
            this.loginProperty.set(login);
        }

        public SimpleStringProperty loginProperty() {
            return this.loginProperty;
        }

        [...]
    }
```

If i start editing the user data in the UI it gets directly updated in the entity:

```
this.login.textProperty().bindBidirectional(user.loginProperty());
```

There is no need for extensive "business logic". It gets all handled via (input) validation. If all input is valid i simply save the data via

```
userService.update(user);
```

Parts of the UserService (exactly: its abstract super-class):

```
public abstract class AbstractService<PK extends Serializable, Type> implements GenericService<PK, Type> {

protected Class<Type> clazz;

@PersistenceContext(name = "JPA-Unit1")
@Inject
protected Provider<EntityManager> emProvider;
    public AbstractService(Class<Type> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public Type create(Type entity) {
        this.emProvider.get().persist(entity);
        return entity;
    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public Type update(Type entity) {
        this.emProvider.get().persist(entity);
        return entity;
    }
}
```

As you can see: the service class is pretty straightforward. I could even delete all this "service"-classes and directly use the entitymanager directly in my UI controller.

In this service you can see the "problem" the user i edit got loaded earlier by its named query and put into a list. The loading is also done in a `@Transactional` method. 
But everytime i call `this.emProvider.get()` I get a new instance with an empty context. And if I want to save the previously edited user I have the problem that persist actually performs an insert (I assume because it is not known in the context [detached]) which leads to an PK-constraint violation or if I delete (`null`) its ID-property there is a new user row inserted.

My actual questions are:
1. Is this approach "OK"? If yes what do I do with this "always" new persistence context? Call contains and merge every single time?

2. Should I get rid of my service class and implement the persistence operations directly in my UI-controller?
3. Can I do an `this.emProvider.get()` once the User-UI-controller got loaded and use it the entire life time of the application?
4. Something totally different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that your app uses Guice Persist.

The answer to this question depends on your use cases; however, you absolutely need to realize one thing:

For as long as an `EntityManager` is open, its underlying persistence context **tracks every single change** to each persistent entity.

This means that if you keep an entity manager open for the duration of the application, whenever you call e.g. `User.setLogin()`, the change you just made is already regarded as persistent. Now, moving to your `update` method, calling `persist` on an entity that is already managed has no effect; however, since you're calling it from a `@Transactional` method, Guice wraps the call in a transaction, and consequently, all the changes are are being flushed to the database once the method ends.

This means that if you modify multiple entities at once within your app, and then call `AbstractService.update` on one of them, you will actually be saving **all the changes your app has done to other entities in the meantime, even if `AbstractService.update` has not been called on them explicitly**.

Using the entity manager-per-transaction approach is indeed much safer. Between transactions, there will be no open persistence context, and as a result all the entities will become detached, which will prevent any updates on them from accidentally being flushed to the database.

However, for the same reason, your `update` method will need to call `em.merge` on the entity you want to update in the database. `merge` is basically telling the entity manager 'please put this entity back into the persistence context, and make it have the exact state that the provided entity has'. Calling `persist` makes it look as though it was a new entity, and PK-constraint violations will indeed follow.

Comment: So you are basically saying, i should stick with the `@Transactional` approach?

Comment: I'm saying that would be the safer option. But you need to use `merge` inside your `update` method

Comment: I built a testcase for both variants. I never noticed this behaviour because until now the edits to user (-entities) are mutually exclusive by UI-design. It was and will not be possible to edit two users at once. But i think i understand why even in my case the transactional approach is better. Until now for me the need to merge entities back into a(nother) context is something i should avoid. Not "expect".